# Override using polymorphism

Tags: python

Override the `go_to_heaven()` method of LivingThings such
that when an animal really `go to heaven`, a `Food` object of name ”
meat” and food value of `animal.get food value()` will be created at the place
where the animal was. E.g. If an animal named ”bear” was killed, a `Food` object
with the name of ”bear meat” will be produced.
To add an object to a Place, you can use the add object method of the Place
object.

Pre-defined code:

```
class LivingThing(MobileObject):
    def __init__(self, name, health, threshold):
        super().__init__(name, None)
        self.health = health
        self.threshold = threshold

    def get_threshold(self):
        return self.threshold

    def get_health(self):
        return self.health

    def add_health(self, health):
        self.health = min(100, self.health+health)

    def reduce_health(self, health):
        self.health = max(0, self.health-health)
        if self.health == 0:
            self.go_to_heaven()

    def go_to_heaven(self):
        self.get_place().del_object(self)
        HEAVEN.add_object(self)
        GAME_LOGGER.add_event("DEAD", self)

class Food(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name, food_value):
        self.name = name
        self.food_value = food_value
    def get_food_value(self):
        return self.food_value
```

Here's my code:

```
class Animal(LivingThing):
    def __init__(self, name, health, food_value, threshold = random.randint(0, 4)):
        super().__init__(name, health, threshold)
        self.food_value = food_value
    def get_food_value(self):
        return self.food_value
    def get_threshold(self):
        return self.threshold
    def go_to_heaven(self):
        self.get_place().add_object(self)
        super().go_to_heaven()
```

For testing my code:

```
BASE.add_object(bear)
print(named_col(BASE.get_objects()))    # ['bear']
print(bear.get_place().get_name())      # Base
bear.go_to_heaven()                     # bear went to heaven!
print(named_col(BASE.get_objects()))    #['bear meat']
```

for the last part i couldn't get 'bear meat', i get 'bear' instead. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your overridden `go_to_heaven` does `self.get_place().add_object(self)`, which adds the Animal to its own place, instead of adding food.

Comment: you know that indentation matters?

Comment: i try adding but failed. How do i modify my code?

Comment: the simplest thing on earth: copy your code from your editor, paste it into the form, mark all of it and press the source code format button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
def go_to_heaven(self):
        self.get_place().add_object(self)
        super().go_to_heaven()
```

with:

```
def go_to_heaven(self):
        self.get_place().add_object(Food('{} meat'.format(self.name), self.food_value))
        super().go_to_heaven()
```

You want to put meat at the place of death, not the ghost of the animal.

Comment: @JoranBeasley And why not. He asked the question in an orderly and polite manner, he showed what he has tried, and identified his stuck. SO is about helping one another, is it not? The fact that it is homework is insubstantial.

Comment: I gave you plus one :P

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thank you so much.. :) But can u please explain to me what this code does?

Comment: There isn't much to explain. It creates a new Food object (using the provided `__init__`) with the necessary name and value, then adds it to the place.

Answer (score 1):

As this seem to be homework, I don't want to give you a full answer, but in

```
def go_to_heaven(self):
    self.get_place().add_object(self)
    super().go_to_heaven()
```

you put the object just back to where it had been before. instead you want to put something else

```
def go_to_heaven(self):
    self.get_place().add_object(** some other object here **)
    super().go_to_heaven()
```